Standard indentation behavior in Emacs 29 (like in the Mousepad, JetBrains WebStorm, VScode)
I want to achieve standard indentation behavior in Emacs 29 (like in the Mousepad, JetBrains WebStorm, VScode, etc.). Without any smart behavior and for all major modes (text-mode, mhtml-mode, etc.). With respect to the editorconfig settings.
Expected Behavior:

Pressing TAB - the current line or all selected lines are shifted
to the right (one indent for each press)
Pressing Shift+TAB -
current line or all selected lines are shifted to the left (one
unindent for each press)

I tried something like:
(keymap-global-set "<TAB>" 'indent-rigidly-right)
(keymap-global-set "<backtab>" 'indent-rigidly-left)

But the result was strange. Sometimes the current line was shifted, sometimes not, sometimes the lines above or below the current one were shifted. And selected text shifting didn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Major and minor modes can redefine TAB and backtab. If you want to override their redefinitions then you need to change those key bindings in those modes. You might be able to just create a minor mode that binds them as you like, depending on whether you luck out with that minor mode having precedence.

I just can't find appropriate command for "dumb" indentation

Define "dumb" indentation. Maybe C-x TAB does what you want? C-h f indent-rigidly.

I need straightforward separated indent/unindent commands. Not only one <tab> command. I need them for languages like pug/jade, stylus and sass which don't have curly braces and therefore auto indentation is not possible.

I fixed it by writing my own functions. Thx.

Here are my own indentation functions with respect to the global settings (indent-tabs-mode and tab-width) and therefore to the Editorconfig. They work as described in the question. Tested on Emacs 29.3.
How to use?
Add this functions to the ~/.emacs file:
(defun dumb-indentation-move-right ()
  "Indent each line with respect to the global settings and therefore to the Editorconfig"
  (interactive)
  (if (use-region-p)
    ;; Add configured indentation string to the left on each line
    (save-excursion
      (let ((start-line (line-number-at-pos (region-beginning)))
             (end-line (line-number-at-pos (region-end))))
        (dotimes (i (+ 1 (- end-line start-line)))
          (goto-line (+ start-line i))
          (insert (dumb-indentation-get-string))))
      (setq deactivate-mark nil))
    ;; When there is no active region, "\t" is always inserted if there are non-whitespace chars presents on the left side of the current point
    (if (string-match "^[\t ]*$" (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (point)))
      (insert (dumb-indentation-get-string))
      (insert "\t"))))

(defun dumb-indentation-move-left ()
  "Unindent each line with respect to the global settings and therefore to the Editorconfig"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((start-line (line-number-at-pos (if (use-region-p) (region-beginning) (point))))
           (end-line (line-number-at-pos (if (use-region-p) (region-end) (point)))))
      (dotimes (i (+ 1 (- end-line start-line)))
        (goto-line (+ start-line i))
        ;; Remove configured indentation string from the left. Otherwise remove all whitespace chars from the left.
        (let ((str (dumb-indentation-get-string)))
          (if (and (>= (length (thing-at-point 'line)) (length str))
                (string-equal str (buffer-substring (point) (+ (point) (length str)))))
            (delete-char (length str))
            (delete-char (string-match "[^\t ]" (thing-at-point 'line)))))
        ))
    (setq deactivate-mark nil)))

(defun dumb-indentation-get-string ()
  "Get indentation string with respect to the global settings and therefore to the Editorconfig"
  (interactive)
  (if indent-tabs-mode "\t" (make-string tab-width ? )))

Then, for example, add this bindings to the ~/.emacs file too:
;; Bind functions to the keys what you want within
;; scope of appropriate major modes. Don't bind it
;; to the global `<tab>` because it breaks autocomplete
;; for minibuffer.

;; <backtab> - that how <shift>+<tab> is named in Emacs

(keymap-set text-mode-map "<tab>" 'dumb-indentation-move-right)
(keymap-set text-mode-map "<backtab>" 'dumb-indentation-move-left)

(keymap-set web-mode-map "<tab>" 'dumb-indentation-move-right)
(keymap-set web-mode-map "<backtab>" 'dumb-indentation-move-left)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please remove everything that doesn't directly answer the question, including "Why I need this". This is a Q&A site: ask a question, provide an answer. Even if you answer your own question, please don't make a blog out of the answer, wandering from just answering the question. Thx.

Corrected. Thanks for your comments.
